# Is there a way to retrieve a value that has already been set on a dropdown select option?

Tags: php, selection, edit, dropdown

I have a create.php which creates a user, and edit.php for editing information of the student.

I'm a beginner in PHP so if this might be a question that has a very easy method, please do tell.

I've been searching for retrieving a value that has already been set on a dropdown, but the only things I've found are:

a.) They only print the selected value, not retrieve the already-set option.

sample code:

```
    <p>Schedule</p>
    <select value="<?= $data->schedule; ?>" name = "schedule">
    <?php
    $schedule = array ('Morning', 'Afternoon');
    foreach ($schedule as $sched) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $sched; ?>"><?php echo $sched; ?></option>
    </select>
    <?php } ?>
```

b.) I have no knowledge of javascript, I tried it, but as I have no knowledge of it, I can't seem to make it work.

sample codes I tried:

```
    <p>Schedule</p>
            <select id = "my_select" name = "schedule">
              <option id = "o1" id="id1">Morning</option>
              <option id = "o2" id="id2">Afternoon</option>
            </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#my_select").change(function() {
      var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id');
    });
    </script>
```

I also tried

```
document.getElementById('schedule').selectedOptions[0].text
```

but still does not output "afternoon"

This is my last resort as I have no other resource to find.

[I added a picture of what I wanted to do since my question might be a little confusing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okVzm.png)

Comment: Why does the top of the image show afternoon and not Afternoon? Where is that coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selects use `selected` attribute not the value to define the selected state.

So in your code check the value and then apply `selected`.

```
<p>Schedule</p>
<select name="schedule">
<?php foreach (['Morning', 'Afternoon'] as $sched): ?>
    <option value="<?= $sched ?>"<?= ($data->schedule == $sched ? ' selected' : null) ?>><?= $sched ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: No worries, you might need to tweek it abit if your storing as `morning` instead of `Morning`.